# Sequence of measurable sets inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in $\mathbb R^m$ and $k \in \mathbb N$. Show that if $G=\{x \in E_n \text{for at least k values of n}\}$, then $G$ is measurable and $k|G| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |E_n|$.

I could show that $G$ is measurable, since $G$ can be expressed as a countable union of a countable intersection of measurable sets:$$G=\cup_{n \geq k} \cap_{j \in \mathcal J,|G|=n} E_{i_j}$$

I don't know how to show the inequality, I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $I_n$ be the indicator function of $E_n$, and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n(x)$.  Integrate.